Error converting .py file into .exe using pyinstaller
"Pyinstaller --name NAME --onefile --windowed python.py"
The above command is used to convert a .py file into a .exe file. The above command gets executed and the .exe file is found inside the dist folder.
While running the .exe file, an error occurs. A snapshot of the error has been pasted below.
Whie runing .exe file 
Pyinstaller --name NAME --windowed python.py.
This commend also tried, but could not get rid of the error.

An error existed with the Anaconda interpreter.
Solution: Install the Python interpreter locally and run the above command. The error will be resolved

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
